# Is there a way to access the "another exceptions" that happen in a python3 traceback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, try-except, traceback

Let's assume you have some simple code that *you don't control* (eg: it's in a module you're using):

```py
def example():
    try:
        raise TypeError("type")
    except TypeError:
        raise Exception("device busy")
```

How would I go about accessing the `TypeError` in this traceback in order to handle it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/google/home/dthor/dev/pyle/pyle/fab/visa_instrument/exception_helpers.py", line 3, in example
    raise TypeError("type")
TypeError: type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/google/home/dthor/dev/pyle/pyle/fab/visa_instrument/exception_helpers.py", line 7, in <module>
    example()
  File "/usr/local/google/home/dthor/dev/pyle/pyle/fab/visa_instrument/exception_helpers.py", line 5, in example
    raise Exception("device busy")
Exception: device busy
```

I can do the below, but i'm not happy with it because I'm doing string comparison - meaning things would break if the underlying module changes what string they raise (I don't control `example()`):

```py
try:
    example()
except Exception as err:
    if "device busy" in str(err):
        # do the thing
        pass
    # But raise any other exceptions
    raise err
```

I'd much rather have:

```
try:
    example()
except Exception as err:
    if TypeError in err.other_errors:  # magic that doesn't exist
        # do the thing
        pass
    raise err
```

or even

```
try:
    example()
except TypeError in exception_stack:  # Magic that doesn't exist
    # do the thing
    pass
except Exception:
```

I'm investigating the `traceback` module and `sys.exc_info()`, but don't have anything concrete yet.

Followup: would things be different if the exception was *chained*? Eg: `raise Exception from the_TypeError_exception`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `__context__` of the exception:

```
>>> try:
...     example()
... except Exception as e:
...     print(f"exception: {e!r}")
...     print(f"context: {e.__context__!r}")
...
exception: Exception('device busy')
context: TypeError('type')
```

If you use a chained exception, the original exception will also be accessible via the `__cause__` attribute.